# CriteriaBuilder, params: find users with specific objects

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to filter my users by competences (licenses and stuff). Right now I'm experimenting with different possibilities but I think I'm stuck and I'm looking for help.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('service_manager')")
    @RequestMapping(path = "/workers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Page<WorkDetailResponse> getWorkers(
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") Integer size,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String name,
            @RequestParam(required = false) BigInteger phone,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String email,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String competences,
            @RequestParam(required = false) User.UserStatus status,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "createTime") String sort,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "desc") String sortDir
            ){

        WorkDetailListRequest request = new WorkDetailListRequest(name, phone, email, competences, roles, status);

        Sort.Direction direction;

        if (sortDir.equals("asc")) {
            direction = Sort.Direction.ASC;
        } else {
            direction = Sort.Direction.DESC;
        }

        return workDetailService.getWorkDetails(request, of(page, size, direction, sort))
                .map(WorkDetailResponse::new);
    }
```

The competences of a worker are actually a Set[] of Competence objects, one worker can have many competences.

```
public Page<WorkDetail> getWorkDetails(WorkDetailListRequest request, Pageable pageable) {
        Specification<WorkDetail> spec = where(null);

        if (request.getName() != null) spec = spec.and(name(request.getName()));
        if (request.getPhone() != null) spec = spec.and(phoneOne(request.getPhone()));
        if (request.getEmail() != null) spec = spec.and(email(request.getName()));
        if (request.getCompetences() != null) spec = spec.and(competences(request.getCompetences()));
        if (request.getRoles() != null) spec = spec.and(roles(request.getRoles()));
        if (request.getStatus() != null) spec = spec.and(status(request.getStatus()));

        return workDetailRepository.findAll(spec, pageable);
    }
```

This is currently the specification I am using.

```
public static Specification<WorkDetail> competences(String competences){
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("competences").get("name"), competences);
}
```

The idea was that using parameters from lets say:

http://localhost:8080/workers?competences=A&competences=B&competences=C

the application would find all workers with competences A,B, and C

Right now I'm getting this error : `Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.competences] of basic type;`, but I'm not doing it right anyway. Has anyone done this before?

Competence and WorkDetail are in a many-to-many relationship

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow multiple competences in the query, then getCompetences() should return a `List<String>`

Your competences method should also have the same argument type, and instead of `equal` you should use `in` when you create the criteria.